# como adicionar copia oculta phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Como faço para enviar newsletter com copia oculta para os clientes, aparecendo apenas o e-mail do mesmo que foi enviado?

código:

```
require_once("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "projeto") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$emails = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   $emails[] = $row['mail'];
   $nome[] = $row['name'];
}


define('GUSER', 'gmailtest@gmail.com'); // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'test123456');       // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para) { 

    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 465;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mailer->AddBCC($emails, $nome);
    $mail->CharSet   = 'utf-8';

    $mail->Subject ="teste de newsletter";
    $mail->Body = 'oi';

    if(count($para) > 1){
      foreach($para as $email){
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
      }
    }else{
        $mail->AddAddress($para);
      }

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 
//o nome do email que envia a mensagem, o Assunto da mensagem e por último a variável com o corpo do email.

 if (smtpmailer($emails)) {


    echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Sua Mensagem foi Enviada com Sucesso!\");
            history.go(-1);
         </script>\n";

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
```

Answer (score 4):

O uso do AddBCC deveria fazer ele funcionar normalmente

```
$mailer->AddBCC("foo@gmail.com", "test");
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
}
```

Tente adicioná-lo antes do comando send, no final de todos os endereços. Note que por ser uma cópia oculta, nem a pessoa que recebeu vai ver o próprio nome nos destinatários.

Veja aqui também:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777862/phpmailer-addbcc-not-working
- http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/157861-problemas-com-c%C3%B3pia-oculta-addbcc-no-phpmailer/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691373/phpmailer-not-sending-cc-or-bcc

Comment: nele o primeiro parametro que eu tenho que adicionar e o endereco de email e o segundo e o nome neh no caso ficaria algo assim baseado no meu  $mailer->AddBCC($emails, $nome); ?

Comment: Sim, se eu não me engano o segundo parâmetro é opcional, pode mandar vazio.